# Wrong cached reputation displayed across sites

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-display

Here's a breakdown of my accounts display on so, meta, german, cooking, sf&f and programmers:

[image: rep display]

As you can see, on some sites the rep display is differing (yellow) from the actual rep on the site (green). I checked at the respective site's /reputation page, and the green boxes seem to be accurate.

Is there a way to refresh the rep display cache? As a side note, the flair rep seems to be off too, it displays 4.4k whereas it should be 4.5.

Comment: *"it's just that I just hate inexplicable inconsistencies"* It's not inexplicable; it's easily explainable by caching. Happy now? :-)

Comment: If the value displayed on page A doesn't equal the value displayed on page B then the answer is usually caching. If it hasn't caught up > 24 hours later then it might be a bug.

Comment: @Chris The last rep change displayed at sf&f was feb 16th, at german it was Feb 1st. Changing to bug ...

Comment: My account shows a similar problem: 170 score at Skeptics, but 169 reported for Skeptics at other sites (and has done for a couple of days) - see http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/6236/energynumbers and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164022/energynumbers?tab=accounts

Comment: Per site rep appears correct on your [SE profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/246114/takrl?tab=accounts), so not really a pressing issue. It could be a minor bug, the easier solution of which would be to forget about your rep all together, it's just an integer on a database somewhere...

Comment: @Yannis I never said it was pressing. But as I see it, this is one of the things meta is for - reporting issues. I can't pinpoint the timing exactly, but now that I think of it, this started to look the way it does now after some of the recent changes were introduced. And since this may well be connected that I think it was worth reporting. Whoever downvoted probably just looked at it from a rep-whoring point of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't exist anymore, because the `Accounts` tab has been removed.